# Compare variable to text disregarding caps

Tags: lua

I need to compare user imput to text but since lua is cap sensitive I'd have to do more than two different comparisons at the same time

```
    a = io.read()
    if a == "check window" or a == "Check Window"
       then
        print("The sky is bright")
       end
```

If I typed `check window` or `Check Window` I'd have no problem but if a user types `CHECK WINDOW` the code won't work, how do I avoid this?

Comment: `if string.lower(a) == "check window" then`